# Maximal solutions of a generalized differential equation for logistic growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ordinary differential equation  for logistic growth is given by
$$\dot{x}(t)=\lambda(t)x(t)(1-x(t))\quad\quad(1)$$
If $\lambda\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and if the initial condition $x(0)=x_0\in(0,1)$ is imposed one may use the standard method of separating the variables to get the solution
$$x\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\,x(t)=(1+c\exp(-\Lambda(t))^{-1},$$ where $\Lambda(t):=\int_0^t \lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s$ and $c=(1-x_0)/x_0$. Thus the maximal open interval $I$ containing $0$ such that (1) with $x(0)=x_0\in(0,1)$ has a solution on $I$ is $\Bbb R$.

Now we could think of a *harvesting* term $\mu\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and replacing (1) by
$$\dot{x}(t)=\lambda(t)x(t)(1-x(t))+\mu(t)\quad\quad(2)$$
Since the right hand side $\lambda x(1-x)+\mu$ is continuous and differentiable with respect to $x$ there is also in this case a maximal interval $I$ and a solution $x$ defined on $I$ such that $x(0)=x_0\in(0,1)$.

*Question*: Is $I$ unbounded to the right, i.e., is $[0,\infty)\subseteq I$?

Comment: You need to put reasonable restrictions on $μ(t)$. Else you can take any ${\cal C}^1$ function $p$ and set $μ(t)=\dot p-λ(t)p(t)(1−p(t))$ to get $p$ as solution of the IVP with $x(0)=p(0)$.

Comment: Many thanks. Would $\mu=\text{const.}$ and $\lambda$ continuous and periodic be a reasonable condition?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found an equation such that maximal solution of a corresponding initial value problem is bounded from above. The problem is
$$I'(t)=I(t)(1-I(t))-\frac{1}{4}, I(0)=\frac{1}{5}$$

Its solution is
$$I(t)=\frac{1}{t-\frac{10}{3}}+\frac{1}{2}.$$
The maximal interval of definition  for this function is $(-\infty,\frac{10}{3})$.

Comment: In context the domain is bounded by $t\le \frac43$, as after that the function value becomes negative, which should not be allowed for a population number.